# How to input a 3-way table?

Tags: r, input, contingency

I have the data in the table form (not even a R table) and I want to transform (or input) it into R to perform analysis.

The table is a 3-way contingency table which looks like this:
[image]

Is there a way to easily input this into R? (It can by any format as long as I can perform some regression analysis)

Or I need to manually input it?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about this image? Or what's your raw input going to be? I'm sure you can read the data in, but you'll likely have to reshape it to do any analysis with it.

Comment: This is exactly the data, it is given like this in a table, for any number or categorical name, I need to manually input by myself.

Comment: So it is an image? Then you might want to track down some OCR software.

Comment: @MrFlick, for small tables like these `read.ftable` is pretty handy though.

Comment: Good point @AnandaMahto. I was thinking of only avoiding re-typing anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In R, this is an `ftable`.

Inputting an `ftable` manually is not too difficult if you know how the function works. The data need to be in a format like this:

```
breathless yes no
coughed    yes no
age
20-24  9  7  95 1841
25-29 23  9 108 1654
30-34 54 19 177 1863
```

If the data are in this format, you can use `read.ftable`. For example:

```
temp <- read.ftable(textConnection("breathless yes no
coughed yes no
age
20-24  9  7  95 1841
25-29 23  9 108 1654
30-34 54 19 177 1863"))
temp
#       breathless  yes        no     
#       coughed     yes   no  yes   no
# age                                 
# 20-24               9    7   95 1841
# 25-29              23    9  108 1654
# 30-34              54   19  177 1863
```

From there, if you want a "long" `data.frame`, with which analysis and reshaping to different formats is *much* easier, just wrap it in `data.frame()`.

```
data.frame(temp)
#      age breathless coughed Freq
# 1  20-24        yes     yes    9
# 2  25-29        yes     yes   23
# 3  30-34        yes     yes   54
# 4  20-24         no     yes   95
# 5  25-29         no     yes  108
# 6  30-34         no     yes  177
# 7  20-24        yes      no    7
# 8  25-29        yes      no    9
# 9  30-34        yes      no   19
# 10 20-24         no      no 1841
# 11 25-29         no      no 1654
# 12 30-34         no      no 1863
```